# Installation issues of hhvm-pgsql on centos 6.5 (64 bit)

Tags: php, postgresql, centos6, yum, hhvm

When I try to install hhvm-pgsql on centos 6.5(64 bit) server the following errors occur.

```
$ yum install hhvm-pgsql

...
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package hhvm-pgsql.x86_64 0:3.0.1-3.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: hhvm = 3.0.1-3.el6 for package: hhvm-pgsql-3.0.1-3.el
6.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: hhvm-pgsql-3.0.1-3.el6.x86_64 (hop5)
           Requires: hhvm = 3.0.1-3.el6
           Installed: hhvm-3.1.0-1.el6.x86_64 (@hop5)
               hhvm = 3.1.0-1.el6
           Available: hhvm-2.3.0-1.el6.x86_64 (hop5)
               hhvm = 2.3.0-1.el6
           ...
           Available: hhvm-3.0.1-3.el6.x86_64 (hop5)
               hhvm = 3.0.1-3.el6
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I also tried these commands
$ rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
$ yum install hhvm-pgsql --skip-broken

result:

```
...
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package hhvm-pgsql.x86_64 0:3.0.1-3.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: hhvm = 3.0.1-3.el6 for package: hhvm-pgsql-3.0.1-3.el
6.x86_64

Packages skipped because of dependency problems:
    hhvm-pgsql-3.0.1-3.el6.x86_64 from hop5
```

hop5 repo:

```
[hop5]
name=www.hop5.in Centos Repository
baseurl=http://www.hop5.in/yum/el6/
gpgcheck=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-HOP5
```

What should I do ? Please help me. 
All answers are highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have `hhvm-3.1.0-1.el6` installed, but `hhvm-pgsql-3.0.1-3.el6` you are installing requires `hhvm-3.0.1-3.el6`. So maybe you want to run something like:

```
# yum remove hhvm
# yum install hhvm-pgsql
```

or ask repository maintainer to rebuild hhvm-pgsql for latest hhvm available.